# Fetch Google Images with this class

Tags: java

Is there a way to list up all img links from google image search with this class?:

```
//The url of the website. This is just an example
private static final String webSiteURL = "http://www.supercars.net/gallery/119513/2841/5.html";

//The path of the folder that you want to save the images to
private static final String folderPath = "<FOLDER PATH>";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        //Connect to the website and get the html
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webSiteURL).get();

        //Get all elements with img tag ,
        Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

        for (Element el : img) {

            //for each element get the srs url
            String src = el.absUrl("src");

            System.out.println("Image Found!");
            System.out.println("src attribute is : "+src);

            getImages(src);

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("There was an error");
        Logger.getLogger(DownloadImages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static void getImages(String src) throws IOException {

    String folder = null;

    //Exctract the name of the image from the src attribute
    int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

    if (indexname == src.length()) {
        src = src.substring(1, indexname);
    }

    indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());

    System.out.println(name);

    //Open a URL Stream
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( folderPath+ name));

    for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
        out.write(b);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```

I am fetching image links from other websites but I cant fetch images just from the google image search. Is it possible to fetch these images with this class or do I have to use another method ?

Comment: I really love your question's title.

Comment: He is already using... @OmurbekKadyrbekov

Comment: English is not my main language, sorry :)

Comment: It's ok, not mine too (:

Comment: why can't you fetch images?

Comment: I can fetch images but not from the gpogle image search